# DB scheme for To do list app with the ability to add a check list

Tags: ios, database-schema

I'm trying to build a "to-do list" iOS app with the ability to add a checklist or progress bar for a specific "to-do" item.

Is the correct approach to create a separate table for checklist and progress bar, and use join to load data for a to-do?

If so, wouldn't I have a lot of tables based on the things I allow the user to add?

Comment: You should consider using code samples when asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: You would only have the couple tables you need, and then a data reference (key) from the progress bar table to the checklist or todo.  Basically a foreign key so all progress entries are in the one table, and they have a reference to your to do table and likely to the checklist.

Comment: I think i got it. Thanks.